# How many "non-trivial" simple laws can we find that give first five elements of the sequence $1,3,6,10,15...$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

About few hours ago there was a question on MSE to figure out a law that generates this sequence: $$\{1,3,6,10,15,...\}$$

It immediately comes to mind that an author of the book in which this question was raised *probably* had a sequence $\frac {n(n+1)}{2}$ in his mind.

And, of course, we all know that questions like this one have an infinite number of different answers but, when I was thinking about actual construction of some law other than this trivial one I was faced with problems.

First, that problems arose because I am an amateur and do not have broader knowledge about constructions in mathematics, and, secondly, it arose because I probably did not take some time in the past to construct "non-trivial" laws that match first few numbers of some sequence.

I took my paper and pencil and found relatively simple law that generates above written first five elements of the sequence $\frac {n(n+1)}{2}$.

Define $b$ as $$b(n)=n^{[\sqrt{n}]}+(-1)^{\lambda(n+6)} \cdot \mod_5 ((n+3)(n+4))$$, where $[\sqrt{n}]$ is integer part of square root of $n$, and $\lambda$ is Louville function that counts number of prime factors of $n$ (counted with multiplicity) and $\mod_5(n)$ gives a remainder when we divide $n$ by $5$

Now, we will define our sequence as $$a(n)=c(n+1)+\pi [1,2^n+\pi[1,b(n)]]$$, where $\pi [a,b]$ denotes number of primes in an interval $[a,b]$ and $c(n)$ is the number of composites $\leq n$

It si trivial to see that our $a(n)$ fulfills our mission and that she gives $1,3,6,10,15$ for $n=1,2,3,4,5$.

I would like to see an examples by you, that are using sequences that are relatively simple, and do not involve too big a numbers in calculation, and that give $1,3,6,10,15$ for $n=1,2,3,4,5$.

Also, I would like to thank OEIS for some help.

**Edit**: I thought that it is obvious that cheating like entering $1,3,6,10,15$ in OEIS is not what I wanted. I used OEIS for help in search of sequences that I needed in order to finish the task.

Comment: [oeis search results](http://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C3%2C6%2C10%2C15&language=english&go=Search) 189 results found.

Comment: @JMoravitz That is a cheating.

Comment: Why do you say "cheating", if you even thank OEIS for some help?

Comment: @DietrichBurde Because I used OEIS in search of sequences that do not start with 1,3,6,10,15. I am quite sure that this sequence of mine is not in  OEIS.

Comment: Without reasonable constraints, this question doesn't make a lot of sense. For example: The sequence $(1,3,6,10,15,-1, \pi, \int, \text{car}, \ldots)$ is a nontrivial extension but probably none that you'd allow.

Comment: Compositions (ordered partitions) of $n+2$ into $3$ parts all of whose parts are less than $6$ will scupper the plan for the sequence to continue as $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$.

Comment: I see that it would be the best that I do not post on this site anymore.

Comment: here is a stupid one $\frac { n(n+1)}{2} +k(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)(n-4)(n-5)$ which will go though the first 5 of the sequence, and then start going elsewhere depending on $k.$

Comment: Feel free to continue posting here, just make sure that your question makes sense and can have a chance at appropriate answers.

Comment: This is a really ill-defined question.

Comment: @JMoravitz Thanks for the support but no, I think that I do not want to do that anymore, I came with good intentions to offer help and to search for help but I am going to do my reserach in math alone from now on, I am not part of academic community and I do not want to be a black sheep here.

Comment: That is your decision to make on your own.  If you can't take criticism, then it might be for the best.  Good luck in whatever it is you decide to do with your time, but I expect wherever you go you will have to face similar criticism unless you become a total shut-in.  It might be healthier to try to understand what was being criticized and what you might do to fix it assuming it needs fixing rather than giving up and ignoring it.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a new idea, probably not listed in OEIS. Take the book ["Buddenbrooks"](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buddenbrooks) by Thomas Mann. Replace the letters $a,b,c,...,z$ by numbers $1,2,\ldots ,26$. Then, on page $5$, consider the last numbers from each word in each sentence. There is a sequence $1,3,6,10,15,16,\ldots$.

Comment: I'm too lazy to check whether that's true. But I'd like to believe it is ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Number of permutations for each possible sum when three standard dice are rolled:

$3 --> 1$

$4 --> 3$

$5 --> 6$

$6 --> 10$

$7 --> 15$

$8 --> 21$

$9 --> 25$

$10 --> 27$

$11 --> 27$

$12 --> 25$

$13 --> 21$

$14 --> 15$

$15 --> 10$

$16 --> 6$

$17 --> 3$

$18 --> 1$

If you want an infinite sequence, all subsequent terms (sum $19$ or greater) are $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Let us look at the general case in which we have a sequence 
$$a_1,a_2,...,a_n.$$

Now define a polynomial of degree $n$

$$p(k)=\sum_{j=0}^{n}b_jk^j,$$

in which we have $n+1$ unknown coefficients. If you use your sequence as data points for your unknown polynomial you will obtain $n$ equations. Adding an arbitrary additional value for the “next number” in the sequence you will be able to determine all coefficients for your polynomial. As you can choose the next number as you wish you have infinitely many polynomials that give the first n elements in the sequence.

**Here is a toy example of the method**

Let us construct a law for $a_1=1,a_2 = 10$.

We start by using an arbitrary polynomial of degree $2$
$$p(n)=b_0+b_1n+b_2n^2$$.

Now, we use the data points that we have:

$$p(1)=1=b_0+b_1+b_2$$
$$p(2)=10=b_0+2b_1+4b_2.$$

Now we add an arbitrary additional number, for example, $1$, hence:

$$p(3)=1 = b_0+3b_1+9b_2$$.

Solving the resulting linear system will give the coefficients $b_0=-26$, $b_1=36$ and $b_2 = -9$. Hence, the law will be $p(n)=-26+36n-9n^2$. If you choose a different third number you will get another solution. Note, that the coefficient matrix has a specific pattern. It is referred as the [Vandermonde matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix).